# React create more/close on button click Type Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I made a function that prints 5 data at a time and prints all data.length when the More button is pressed.

But there is a problem.
Every time I click the button I get an error.

To illustrate my code, I first create a visible state and only display 5 at first.
'expanded' say 'true all product calls' away when clicked on a 'button'
`false show only the first 5'

```
   const [visible, setVisible] = useState(5)
    const [expanded, setexpanded ] = useState(false);

    const showMore = () => {
        visible === 5 ? (
           setVisible(ProductDetail.allergies.length)
        ) (
           setexpanded(true)
        ) : ( 
           setVisible(5)
        ) (
            setexpanded(false)
           
        )

  return (

 {ProductDetail && ProductDetail.allergies?.length ? 
                            ProductDetail.allergies.slice(0, visible).map(All => (
                            <li key={All.id}>
         {All.displayText}</li>
                        )) : <li>No information.</li>}
)


    
                    <button type="button" onClick={showMore}>
                        {expanded ? (
                            <span>close</span>
                        ) : (
                            <span>see more</span>
                        )}  
                    </button>
                    

    }
```

But every time I click the button I get an error.

TypeError: setVisible(...) is not a function

```
  46 | 
  47 |    
  48 |    const showMore = () => {
> 49 |        visible === 5 ? (
  50 |          setVisible(ProductDetail.allergies.length)
  51 |        ) (
  52 |           setexpanded(true)
```

I don't know how to solve it.
How would you like to modify the code?
Oh, and I want to make the buttons invisible if there are less than 5 at first, but I don't know how to write the code.

Comment: It looks like you are calling it like `setVisible(whatever)(setexpanded(true))`, which is the syntax for calling a function that returns a function, then calling the returned function.

Comment: Instead I would probably write `setexpanded(!expanded)` and then `useEffect(() => setVisible(expanded ? allergies.length : VISIBLE_INIT), [expanded]);`

Comment: @windowsill  
I solved it with javascript if else statement.
But for products with less than 5, I want to set the button to be invisible, but I don't know how to set it.

Comment: You're already doing lots of conditional rendering

Comment: @windowsill I don't know how to write it. Click on it to disappear. It doesn't disappear when rendering

Comment: @windowsill ```code  <ButtonBox>
                                {
                          visible >= 4  ? 
                    <button type="button" onClick={showMore}>
                        {expanded ? (
                            <div><span>close</span><img src={Vector190}/></div>
                        ) : (
                            <div><span>the more</span><img src={Vector189}/></div>
                        )}  
                    </button>
                            : null
                        }
                         </ButtonBox>```